# Как повесить обработчик событий onKeyPress на body в react typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook

Хочу, что-бы при клике на клавишу Enter я открывал свой dropdown. Для этого как я понимаю нужно повесить обработчик событий на body.Как это сделать? Хочу просто менять state на true при клике на Enter.
[image: Мой dropdoan]

Comment: в чем именно трудность отслеживать нажатие и при нажатии ентера менять стейт?

Comment: Пробовал поставить обработчик на контейнер вызвав функцию onKeyEnter (onKeyPress={onKeyEnter}).Ничего не получается. В функции такой код  const onKeyEnter = (event: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      setIsActive(true)
    }
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272207/to-call-onchange-event-after-pressing-enter-key возможно поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `useEffect` добавить слушатель события на `document` (только нужно использовать событие `keydown` вместо `keypress`):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      setIsActive((prev) => !prev);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>Press Enter: {isActive ? "active" : "not active"}</div>;
}
```

[Ссылка на рабочий пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-firefly-c3bnv?file=/src/App.tsx)